# Windows Server 2012 R2 & SQL Server 2012 Memory low usage

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I can't find solution for my problem...

We have a Windows Server 2012 R2 and SQL Server 2012 installed on it. I have not installed this server so I can't say if there are some allocation of resources for each user made on start.

My issue is that if I connect to server via remote desk and run queries, they take really long to execute even if it's a short query, indexes / key are set but I found in task manager that I can't get over 200GB memory usage for SQL Server.

The max memory setting in SQL Server is set to 2147483647

Where can I find if I have only some amount of memory allocated to mine account?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Memory usage may not be always an issue.You an check if queries are waiting for memory grants using below dmvs

--below dmv gives me text of queries which are waiting for memory grants

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants mg
 join
sys.dm_exec_requests ec
 on ec.session_id=mg.session_id
 --left join
 --sys.dm_exec_connections con
 --on con.session_id=ec.session_id
 outer apply
 sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec.sql_handle) txt
 outer apply
 sys.dm_exec_query_plan(ec.plan_handle) qp
```

Further you can check which memory clerk is using most memory

```
select (sum(pages_kb)*128)/1024 as 'sizein_mb',type as 'clerkttype'
from sys.dm_os_memory_clerks
group by type
order by (sum(pages_kb)*128)/1024 desc
```

Prior to this,you may need to check if you are having locking,blockings

```
select 
 session_id,status,blocking_session_id,wait_type,txt.text from sys.dm_exec_requests ec
cross apply
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec.sql_handle) txt
```

Hope this helps in your troubleshooting.Checking memory from task manager wont get you accurate stats..below question and answer has reason and some good links to check further.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35418/why-is-sql-server-memory-showing-in-task-manager

Comment: [results][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DTyXy.jpg

i am not sure where the problem is , we have other server and that have less CPU's but 2 TB ram and the same set of querys runs there 20min and on this server it takes like 2 hours .. tables and keys / indexes are same ...

Comment: the question you have asked for seemed like generic slowness for even small queries,as per your sreenshots,it seems only one query (UDF) is having an issue with memorygrant  of nearly 200000 KB,could you confirm if it is an issue with this one alone or generalized?

Comment: its not only this , that query that run is kinda really badly done , it was from previous collegue and i rewrite all but even joining 3 tables, 1 have 1000 rows around  other 44000 and 3rd is calendar takes really long to execute, 7 mins. and on other server its done in 20 sec ..

Comment: please post the query and also the execution pplan